# PHPMailer failed Yahoo SMTP connection

Tags: phpmailer

Wrote a simple script to test PHPMailer from localhost. It failed to connect. Read some posts regarding the issue but none worked.

```
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
        $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = 'xxxx@yahoo.com';
        $mail->Password = 'xxxx';
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Port = 587;  
        $mail->From = 'xxxx@yahoo.com';
        $mail->FromName = 'xxxx';
        $mail->addAddress('xxxx@yahoo.com', 'xxxx');

        $mail->addReplyTo('xxxx@yahoo.com', 'xxxx');

        $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer';
        $mail->Body    = 'PHPMailer';

        if(!$mail->Send()) {
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
```

Below are the error messages:

2020-04-11 07:58:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.mail.yahoo.com ESMTP ready
2020-04-11 07:58:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2020-04-11 07:58:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp417.mail.bf1.yahoo.com Hello localhost [207.216.100.238])250-PIPELINING250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-8BITMIME250-SIZE 41697280250 STARTTLS
2020-04-11 07:58:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2020-04-11 07:58:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2020-04-11 07:58:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2020-04-11 07:58:11 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2020-04-11 07:58:11 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed:
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

You can try with other SMTP (for example Google, Microsoft).

What is wrong specifically?

You can visit this page for more information is about how configure it.
[Yahoo SMTP settings](https://www.saleshandy.com/smtp/yahoo-smtp-settings/)

Comment: I am new to PHPMailer. I don't exactly know what's causing it. The yahoo security setting has different setup now. It does not allow less secure option. Instead it provides one time app password but PHPMailer is not on the list. I tried Others option but it didn't work neither.

Answer (score 0):

read through the wiki doc regarding the issue. it turned out i needed to overwrite some of the setting as a trade off to make it work.

```
        $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            )
        );
```

however, it worked for hotmail but not yahoo. i guess it's due to different security measures by different hosts. it is going to be an issue to test codes in localhost environment.